# Not able to import namespaces automatically in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to C#, I have been working on Java. So when I write any class name in Visual Studio, VS do not import or show suggestions to import namespaces,unlike we do in my Eclipse by `CTRL+SPACE`.

I used `CTRL + .(dot)` and `CTRL+SHIFT+F10` but they did not help. I am really frustrated, please suggest any idea.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ensure that in your project you add references to those namespaces. Than the intellisense in your IDE will work to direct you to the correct library within that namespace. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a namespace in a different DLL in your project, you first need to right-click **references** and select "**add reference**" and then checkmark the dll.

After doing this, CTRL+DOT will work :)

If it is a reference to an external package, such as NuGet, you can right-click the solution file and choose "Restore Nuget Packages"

Comment: Sorry,this question will look childish but still i want to ask.I have created a console application and without importing System namespace if i write console in Main() it does not show intellisense.Now what should i do?

Comment: If you type the word "Console" and hit CTRL + Dot (period) then VS will offer you to add a "Using System" statement, which basically means it wants to include the system namespace.